# Resend HTML Form normally on jQuery ajax fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

#### Background:

I want to submit my HTML form asynchronously using jQuery, except if the ajax call fails. **If the ajax call fails, I want to re-submit my HTML form normally.**

I cannot get the "submit normally on fail" to work. What happens is if the submit button is pressed again after a `fail`, it submits normally, but I want the form to be resubmitted automatically on fail.

I am using namespaces because I need the generic `.on('submit', ...)` to always populate the hidden field.

#### Question:

How do I need to redesign my code so that I can achieve the functionality I desire?

#### Code:

```
$('#form).on('submit', function(event){
    $(this).find('#hidden_field').val('value');
});

$('#form').on('submit.as_ajax', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var post = $.post({
        data: $this.serialize(),
        url: $this.attr('action')
    });
    post.done(function(response, status, xhr){
        $('#container').html(response);
    });
    post.fail(function(xhr, status, error){
        $this.off('submit.as_ajax').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
function submitFormNormally($this) {
     $this.submit();
}

function submitFormAsAjax($this) {
    var post = $.post({
        data: $this.serialize(),
        url: $this.attr('action')
    });
    post.done(function(response, status, xhr){
        $('#container').html(response);
    });
    post.fail(function(xhr, status, error){
        submitFormNormally($this);
    });
}
$('#submit-button').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var $this = $('#form');
   submitFormAsAjax($this); 
});
```

Now, what you have to do is bind the submit button like this.

Comment: Yes, I checked your answer. Your code simply recursively calls the ajax request on fail. This is not at all what I am looking for. Thanks for trying :)

Comment: Douglas, completely misunderstood your question. I have updated the code now. Please check